# What data structure to use?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, hashmap, chaining

I need to store the following data;

```
Clampls = {"23e23e", "ff333g", "fhgswq"," h65h3", "ffwwf", "34rf3"}
KJAS3.2 = {"f34f4f", "43rf2d", "3rfas1"," 1122d", "fff42", "ff33f"}
...
```

I was thinking of storing it something like this

```
 Name        Tokens
  .       -> ... , ... , ... , ...
  .       -> ... , ... , ... , ...
Clampls   -> "23e23e" , "ff333g" , "fhgswq" , ... 
KJAS3.2   -> "f34f4f" , "43rf2d" , "3rfas1" , ...  
  .       -> ... , ... , ... , ...
  .       -> ... , ... , ... , ...
```

So sort of like a HashMap. I did some reading in my book *Data Structures & Algorithms in Java, R. Lafore* and i found what i need which is `Separate Chaining / HashChain` however they explain it using own built data structure classes.

Is there a "ready made" collection for a HashChain that i can use in java? Something like

```
Map<String, []String> theMap = new HashMap<String, []String>(); //just an example
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<String>> dataStructure = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

dataStructure.put("Clampls", Arrays.asList("23e23e", "ff333g", "fhgswq"," h65h3", "ffwwf", "34rf3"));
dataStructure.put("KJAS3.2", Arrays.asList("f34f4f", "43rf2d", "3rfas1"," 1122d", "fff42", "ff33f"));

dataStructure.put("KJAS3.3", new ArrayList<String>());
dataStructure.get("KJAS3.3").add("fhgswq");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, so this answer could be off. If you want to have several values for a given key, you should use a MultiMap. There isn't an implementation in the JDK, but plenty of them in common libs, e.g. Google Guava (contains former Google Collections).

Alternatives like `Map<String,List<String>>` work, but are awkward to use, e.g. you have to create the "inner" List yourself if a key doesn't exist.

Comment: Is it really worth to add a new dependency to another lib and memorize another API just to avoid `Map<String, List<String>>`?

Comment: @Andreas_D, I'd say yes. Guava is a fantastic library and the MultiMap collection will save him time in the long run.

Comment: @Andreas: It depends. As bigger the project is, as more likely you need this functionality again, or other features from this lib. Especially Guava contains a lot of useful stuff. And don't forget that the do-it-yourself approach has some problems, too (performance, subtle errors could be overlooked, complicated "API")